# Taking value from other JS file

Tags: javascript

I have a script which takes values directly, below is the code for that

```
    var z=new SuggestComboBase("combo_zone4","alfa4",200);
    z.addOption([[1,"Ahemedaabaad"],[2,"Bangalore"],[3,"Chennai"],[4,"Durgapur"],[5,"Firozaabad"]]);
    z.enableFilteringMode(true);
```

I want to take this values from an external JS file.I am new to JavaScript and hope to have a good answer here. Thanks in advance.

Comment: if 'z' is in public, you can access value anywhere in included page. plz share more code and what you tried, what is the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JS files are not really referenced from one to another. You can think that they are just being merged. So in your case, you can do something like this:

**variables.js**:

```
var myConfig = {
    arrayValues: [
      [1,"Ahemedaabaad"],
      [2,"Bangalore"],
      [3,"Chennai"],
      [4,"Durgapur"],
      [5,"Firozaabad"]
    ];
}
```

**main.js**:

```
z.addOption(myConfig.arrayValues);
```

**HTML**:

```
<script src="variables.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="main.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

This is okay for dev, but good practice is to merge and minify all the javascript files for production environment.